# Why is the whole website highlighted when I click on the css-grid area in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-grid

This only happens in Firefox (and TOR).

This is my code:

```css
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.box,
.empty_box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  display: -moz-box;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box_link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
}

@media(max-width: 379px) {
  .box {
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 100%!important;
    padding: 10px 0px 90px 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-areas: "i t";
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  }
  .box_link {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 14px;
  }
  .box_inner {
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 380px) {
  #main {
    grid-row-gap: 38px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 114px);
  }
  .box {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-areas: "i" "t";
    text-align: center;
    height: 114px!important;
    width: 114px!important;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
  .box_inner,
  .box_inner img {
    height: 100px!important;
    width: 100px!important;
  }
  .box:hover,
  .empty_box:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px #A1D6FF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px #A1D6FF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px #A1D6FF;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 498px) {
  #main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 114px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 624px) {
  #main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 114px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 746px) {
  #main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 114px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 868px) {
  #main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 114px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  #main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 114px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  #main {
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
  #main {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 133px);
    grid-column-gap: 18px;
  }
  .box {
    height: 133px!important;
    width: 133px!important;
  }
  .box_inner,
  .box_inner img {
    height: 118px!important;
    width: 118px!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="main" style="background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);">
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAACOElEQVR4nO3VSW7EMAxEUd3/0sk2ncRtlaoo0ehPQCsNHJ4BjzHG1671O9Tzd/fVffX9TQsQQACZA0mHOzAXvLo+NwAJ1+cGIOH63AAkXJ8bMog7kPTA3ffc+qrnAwgggAACyHxD6YG6+dx9QAABpHI+gACi7bv1VNcHCCCAAPImPh7EDXXgu++nPxi3PkAA6XUfkGb324NUr90DS+9vWoAA0nTggDxsf8v6U0XjSH8Ad+dPRI8qJgOQZgFIs/gIEKWg6h9aOp/bj3o/VD8ggAACyGNAKhNGCty4VICKfIAA0ncB0my1A3EHrO6773X/INR+xxiAACIU6A7UvQ8IINmf+ulwQdL5l1aywdMBCCDS+4Dc7D8eRG0gPQC1OfW96vqn3pcvAALI7HuArCQE5O79+YSnB7LYYKzedH0XZwABZLJAQACR4jiImuD0wN16Di1AAAEEkEeCuANTB5oe+O78RR8AIKv5AQEEkFYgagK3QTefet8FcN+/qBkQQAAB5DEgcpfBqAY+Db5yHhBAfiQH5O8ZuYpgAPLvGa/JyoGo76lxur6Le4AAsqlhdSC76wPEzJ+u7xYkHW5D1QNzgV2AizOAAHKxDwggzwI5PTC1wW5rsX5AAAEEEEACIGqD6vvu+aJ+AVk9X9QvIKvni/oFZPV8Ub/nQNIDTA+o+jwgxQN25wcIIO8DkBsQN1yQ0/nTHyQggGQHcjo/IIC8glQvt2B3oO55Nf9ivYAAMjkQQAABBJDX9Q1NSIF+JJyzxQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAACOElEQVR4nO3VSW7EMAxEUd3/0sk2ncRtlaoo0ehPQCsNHJ4BjzHG1671O9Tzd/fVffX9TQsQQACZA0mHOzAXvLo+NwAJ1+cGIOH63AAkXJ8bMog7kPTA3ffc+qrnAwgggAACyHxD6YG6+dx9QAABpHI+gACi7bv1VNcHCCCAAPImPh7EDXXgu++nPxi3PkAA6XUfkGb324NUr90DS+9vWoAA0nTggDxsf8v6U0XjSH8Ad+dPRI8qJgOQZgFIs/gIEKWg6h9aOp/bj3o/VD8ggAACyGNAKhNGCty4VICKfIAA0ncB0my1A3EHrO6773X/INR+xxiAACIU6A7UvQ8IINmf+ulwQdL5l1aywdMBCCDS+4Dc7D8eRG0gPQC1OfW96vqn3pcvAALI7HuArCQE5O79+YSnB7LYYKzedH0XZwABZLJAQACR4jiImuD0wN16Di1AAAEEkEeCuANTB5oe+O78RR8AIKv5AQEEkFYgagK3QTefet8FcN+/qBkQQAAB5DEgcpfBqAY+Db5yHhBAfiQH5O8ZuYpgAPLvGa/JyoGo76lxur6Le4AAsqlhdSC76wPEzJ+u7xYkHW5D1QNzgV2AizOAAHKxDwggzwI5PTC1wW5rsX5AAAEEEEACIGqD6vvu+aJ+AVk9X9QvIKvni/oFZPV8Ub/nQNIDTA+o+jwgxQN25wcIIO8DkBsQN1yQ0/nTHyQggGQHcjo/IIC8glQvt2B3oO55Nf9ivYAAMjkQQAABBJDX9Q1NSIF+JJyzxQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="http://localhost:3000/sp/r/2">
      <div class="box ui-droppable" data-boxid="2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="box_inner box_pic ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="qrcode2" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; z-index: auto;" title="http://facebook.com">
          <canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img alt="Scan me!" style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
        <span class="box_link" style="font-size: 1em;" title="Facebook">
            Facebook
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>



</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alphatier/csuk0km7/

Please click on the area next to the divs for example. I don't understand why everything is highlighted when I do that.

I found out that it's only because of css-grid.

Everything works fine without..

```
display: grid;
```

.. but then, my structure is destroyed. I want to use css-grid, but I don't want the unnecessary highlighting...

Comment: It seems to have something to do with floating the boxes. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/csuk0km7/1/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using CSS3 technologies such as Grid and Flexbox, there's really no need to use floats. The idea behind these new layout systems was to provide a better method than floats. So you can remove the `float: left` you have applied to your grid layout. This also happens to solve the Firefox highlighting problem.

Comment: It was my intention to replace the float technology with grids (because I'm trying to make my site (more) responsive). And it seems that I forgot to delete that snippet. But I did also not expect that Mozilla Firefox highlights my whole page because of that instead of ignoring the redundant code. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are using float along with flexbox.Remove that and it will work.

To answer your question, If you don't mind the fact that users won't be able to highlight the content, you can use the following css:

```
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

You can just use this rule for Firefox if you wish.